# Unity - WWW class "couldn't connect to host"

Tags: c#, php, web, unity-game-engine

After research, I decided to use PHP to send mail via Web player app, since you can't use System.net.mail on this platform.

On the php side, everything is fine, I use swift mailer and the gmail smtp. When the file is hosted and I call it via a browser it works fine & send the mails.

I host my web app on the same server, here's my C# code to call the php script :

```c#
public string phpUrl = "http://myAdress/sendMail.php";

    public void SendMail ()
    {
        StartCoroutine(loadPhpMail());
    }

    private IEnumerator loadPhpMail()
    {
        WWW postPhp = new WWW (phpUrl);
        yield return postPhp;

        if (postPhp.error != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("error : "+postPhp.error);
        }
        else
        {
            if (postPhp.text=="true")
            {
                Debug.Log("success");
            }
        }
    }
```

And the line "Debug.Log("error : "+postPhp.error);" returns "error : couldn't connect to host".

I did my research work, and couldn't find a workaround.
I tried some things like add a crossdomain policy to the serv.

Thank's guys for reading this.
Bye !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changing the encoding of the crossdomain.xml in ANSI.
Nothing to do with the error message but solved anyway.
Thank's guys

Answer (score 1):

Your URL is not valid (it's a relative URL): `myAdress/sendMail.php`

You need to use an address like this one (click the link to see an example use of WWW) with "http://" prefix and full URL including domain name:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html

Comment: Thank you for your response,
When I posted this thread I replaced my URL. 
But the URL is fine in the real script.

Comment: then you should update your question to reflect that also try looking at the `URI` Class under the following `UriKind.Relative`

Comment: Done, thanks. 
I'm looking into URI class & will post about any updates.

Comment: And also please pay attention that: Server must listens GET method of HTTP you are doing GET. If server listens POST you can use [WWWForm](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.html)